# Sharepoint 2013 - News Feed - Users can't contribute

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, newsfeed

I have a news feed webpart which I have added to a page of the root site collection. I am able to post feeds and view them but all other users cannot. I have changed the permissions for this page to stop inheriting from parent and have set the all users group to contribute permissions. I am having no luck at all.

I have tried creating a separate permissions group, another permissions level, shared the page with the group. Tried setting the target audience of the web part. Still no change. Does anyone have an insight? I really don't know how to get a result.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on the list named "MicroFeed" (this is the list where newsfeeds are stored). Users need to have permission on this to add/edit/delete.